# How big is an integer?

Tags: c

What is the correct way to work out how many bytes an int is? and how do I write an int to a file descriptor?

Here is a mock code sample which might make clear what I am trying to achieve:

```
char *message = "test message";
int length = strlen(message);
int fd = open(file, O_CREAT|O_RDWR);
write(fd, length??, ??); // <--- what goes here
write(fd, message, length);
```

*I dont care about platform independence and byte order, just that it can compile on as many platforms as possible.*

Comment: @ leppie Why did you make this a comment and not an answer? It's exactly right.

Comment: @Swiss: incredulity at someone programming C and not knowing sizeof? Heck, I've written less than 500 lines of C code in my life and know about it.

Comment: @Swiss: I wasn't sure that was what the OP was looking for, and extra rep does not really bother me :)

Comment: You've got to start somewhere.

Comment: It seems strange that you want it to compile on as many platforms as possible, but it's OK that files are incompatible between platforms. It's OK for some local temporary cache file, but generally you do want to write the same bytes to the file for the same value of length.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, it is basically a cache file. i.e. Im trying to write intermediate data used as part of processing steps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sizeof(length)` goes in the field.

It is preferable over using `sizeof(int)` in case you ever change the type of `length` in the future.

`sizeof` expresses the, well, size of a data type in multiples of `sizeof(char)`, which is always 1.

Comment: I've heard that sizeof returns the size of a datatype in bytes, and I've heard that sizeof returns the size of a datatype in units of sizeof(char). But char isn't defined to be 1 byte in the C standard. Which is correct?

Comment: Using sizeof(variable) is better than using sizeof(type). That way, if you change the type of the variable, there's no danger of the call to sizeof falling out of sync.

Comment: @Swiss: It's the other way around: 1 byte is defined to be the size of a char in C.

Comment: @schot 1 byte is defined to be the minimum size of a char in C, but larger sizes are allowed as well.

Comment: `sizeof` when applied to `unsigned char`, `char` is always 1. It's defined in the C standard. That 1 byte could be 8 bits, it could be 9 bits, it could be more depending on platform. http://c-faq.com/charstring/wchar.html expounds on this. I do not have a copy of the C89/C90 standard, but in C99, this is section 6.5.3.4.

Comment: @ schot, biiryree I see now. In C, 8 bits != 1 byte. 1 byte = number of bits in a char.

Comment: The C99 definition of byte says it is the smallest addressable unit large enough to hold a char.  sizeof returns a size in bytes and sizeof(char) returns 1.

Comment: @Swiss: that's pretty much it, although C "bytes" must be *at least* 8 bits wide.  Whether a C "byte" maps directly to a native machine byte is an issue for the compiler implementor.  Harbison & Steele describe a machine that uses 7 bits for characters and 36 bit words for everything else; 1 word can hold 5 characters with 1 bit unused, and all other types take up 1 or more words.  Since most C programs rely on the ability to map any type onto an array of `char`, that means the implementation must use a 9- or 36-bit "byte" which gets mapped onto the native byte, with a performance penalty.

Answer (score 2):

sizeof is your friend.

```
write(fd, &length, sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 2):

sizeof(int)  = 4 (on Linux, 32 & 64 Bit x86-Architecture)
sizeof(long) is 4 on 32 Bit, 8 on 64 Bit (on Linux, x86-32/64-Architecture)
Dunno about Windows.

Comment: `sizeof(long)` stays 4 on 64-bit Windows (tested in XP x64, Vista x64, and Windows 7 x64).

Comment: @birryree: did you compile _for_ x64, or merely on x64, and ran on x64?

Comment: @wnoise: I compiled targeting 64-bit. This is also documented at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b2e7499(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @wnoise: I can confirm it, it stays 32 bit on Windows. Windows uses another convention than modern Linux/Unix/Mac...

Answer (score 0):

```
write(fd, &length, sizeof(length));
```

You can use `sizeof` with variable names or type names. In this case you could have done `sizeof(int)`.

The `write` function takes the address of the memory zone you want to write, so you use the `&` (address of) operator. You don't have to do it for the string because you already have a pointer (`char*`).